# Django: how to test custom request attribute?

Tags: django

I have a django app that uses a custom middleware module to create a subdomain attribute in all requests. This attribute is assigned a string. Everything works during system testing, but I would like to run automated tests on this attribute so my question is:

When I generate a request during unit testing how do I set request.subdomain to a string value so I can test the code? Do I need to create a custom request and then feed it into the test client? Thanks for your time.

### Solution Below

The custom middleware reads the HTTP_HOST string and saves the subdomain in the attribute request.subdomain. My problem was in how to squirt the subdomain request into the client during unit testing. Here's how:

The test Client object allows you to preset any of the key:value pairs in the request.META dictionary. When running tests if you want to set the host name to a subdomain, do it like so:

```
host = 'subdomain1.test.com:8000' 
c = Client(HTTP_HOST=host)
response = c.get(path='/home')
```

And the test will execute as if someone typed `subdomain1.test.com:8000/home` in the browser.

Comment: Are you sure this should be middleware and not a context processor?

Comment: @dave:  Your solution is more clear than the one you accepted (and ultimately, your's is the one that resolved the problem).  You should make it into an answer, and make it the selected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All middlewares work normally during testing. So you can test the whole view (and check if it returns something specific for your request) - it's functional testing. Or you can create a `MockRequest` and pass it directly to your middleware's `process_request` - it is unit testing. Actually, I'd use both altogether.

Comment: Your comments helped me figure out the solution (and give me ideas for new tests.) Thanks!